# Multiple entity jars vs incremental build

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, persistence

I serve entity jars throu a dynamic maven artifact. During a database-schema change the entity-jar produces a new version, no big deal. So in the project's `pom.xml` I change from version

```
<artifactId>rm</artifactId>
<version>2019.12.25.09.18.12</version>
```

to

```
<artifactId>rm</artifactId>
<version>2019.12.31.10.13.41</version>
```

Then I call `mvn tomcat:run`.

What I expect is a clean start using the changed entitys. Unfortunately both entity versions are part of the webapp's classpath. See this screenshot:

[image]

The old version of the jars is loaded first and have higher priority in the webapp. The new entitys are not used.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `mvn clean tomcat:run`

Comment: This works buuut is a bad idea.

Comment: Why its a bad idea?

Comment: Normal usage brings unexpected behavior. You need extra experience to use that workaround. Eclipse wont give a hint to do so. We can not use LATEST as version. Problems occoure late so it is not failfast.

Comment: Can you explain what a dynamic maven artifact is? Please show the pom file ....furthermore what kind of commands have you used? Running on plain command line? Which maven versions etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Its hard to map answers if the questions are not numerated but I hope you can map my answers by yourself. 1. Dynamic Maven Artifact is an artifact produced by the repository at runtime. 2. Whatfor do you need the complete pom? The only command I have used is `mvn tomcat:run`. 3. Sure, on windows I use the classic cmd-command-line. 4. Maven 3.5.2 on Oracle JDK1.8.0_212.

Comment: An artifact is not produced by a repository. It's produced by a build process. Either your own one or you consume existing ones via a repository. if you only use a goal like `mvn tomcat:run` the tomcat plugin handles things and if you change the version in between the plugin does not handle the case correct based on changing the dependencies between the calls...So you have to use once a `mvn clean package tomcat:run`..?...The pom file will show how you have configured tomcat/other plugins etc. and deps...which helps to answer questions...

Comment: @khmarbaise Well the repository have the db-connection and compiles the entitys. https://ibb.co/Gxj4jvN

Answer (score 0):

Maven will cache the results of fetching an artifact from a repository and place it in your ~/.m2/repository folder. If you are building locally without an intermittent clean, your target folder will also contain both old and new versions of the library. The one that appears in your classpath first is based on lexicographical ordering and given the version format you use, older versions will *always* appear before newer versions.

As @karthikeyan-vaithilingam recommends, perform a clean before any execution so that you start with a known state. There is nothing wrong with using clean and it is assumed that any automated build process will start with an empty target folder.

Starting from an unknown state will create issues where one is unable to reproduce the issue in another environment (i.e., it works on my box) thus making it more difficult to find and correct the issue.

If your code requires both the old and new versions of a definition. You should consider how you are managing your dependencies. You can either package them in the same artifact or declare separate dependencies in your POM. In either case, they should exist in separate Java packages so that you can have code that works with both versions of an entity.